# What date format is this API returning?

Tags: datetime

I'm getting this from an API - this date relates to 30th June 1983:

`[DateOfBirth] => /Date(425775600000+0100)/`

So what data type is this? The API doc says it's DateTime but I've not come across it looking like that before. I need to be able to decode and re-encode into whatever this format is.

Thanks.

Comment: +0100 is the time zone. 425775600000 is the date, probably in miliseconds. But its not UNIX time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is unix time in **milli**-seconds.

Unix time is given in seconds since 1st January 1970, so

425775600

maps to

30.06.1983 01:00:00

(with an offset due to timezone).

Use a tool like this to verify:

http://www.gaijin.at/olsutc.php

Comment: @David - nice link: much nicer format etc. than the one I use!

Comment: Thank Java for the milliseconds part of the arrangement.

Comment: timestamps are in milliseconds in javascript by default

Answer (score 3):

As noted by [Havenard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156811/havenard), the core format is 'milliseconds since the Unix Epoch' with a timezone offset of one hour.

```
$ timestamp -u 425775600
425775600 = Wed Jun 29 23:00:00 1983
$
```

That's a non-standard program, but it gives the information; the `-u` means 'Use `gmtime()`', and the fact that it is an hour before midnight on 30th Jun 1983 is due to the one hour time zone offset.

(The Unix Epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00 — midnight on 1st January 1970 at UTC.)

Answer (score 1):

The format is a proprietary one that was developed by Microsoft in their `JavaScriptSerializer` class used in ASP.Net.  You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_sidebarb) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/18/dates-and-json.aspx).

Then you can read about some of [the nightmares this caused](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx).

This format, while still supported, is not recommended any more.  Microsoft have moved away from `JavaScriptSerializer` and the aweful `JsonContractDataSerializer` class, and are now using the [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library.

Originally, that library used the Microsoft format as its default.  But that was changed in 4.5.  It now uses ISO8601 formatted dates.  [Read here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DatesInJSON.htm).

The fact is - JSON does not specify *any* particular format for dates or times.  People had differing opinions early on, but these are now solidifying around mostly-unanimous support for ISO8601.  Specifically the profile described in [RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) is the standard that should be used, such as:

```
2013-05-14T10:30:00-07:00
```